# Searching for exact phrase seems broken

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, search, exact-phrase-search

Perhaps my expectation is incorrect, but the [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page makes it seem as if searching for a phrase delimited by quotes will return results that match the exact phrase *only*.

(Again perhaps this is just a matter of bad expectations, probably set by the way Google would treat this input, because reading the search tips page for a second time I noticed that it doesn't state that it will search for the **exact** phrase only).

For example, I'm interested in checking to see if there are any SO posts on the Apache library "commons-chain", so I search for a few of these variations:

- [java] commons-chain
- [java] "commons-chain"
- "commons-chain"`

With each of the search terms, it seems as if articles are returned not because they match the exact phrase "commons-chain" but because they match either "commons" or "chain".

Perhaps the presence of the hyphen in the URL to the search is throwing things off?

[Google shows the exact type of search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22commons-chain%22&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions) I would expect for search terms like this.

Again, not sure if this truly counts as a bug since it could just be incorrect expectations on my part - but if this is not the designed behavior, I would certainly vote for a feature change to *make* this the designed behavior when searching with quotes.

Comment: Google is still often the best way to search SO/SU/SF.

Comment: "This could be SU" == should be on superuser? But it's a question about how the search functionality works / is intended to work

Comment: I feel like I've said something like this before, but you have to encode the `"` as `%22`.

Comment: It seems like it still doesn't work - shouldn't `status-complete` tag be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try now:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%22commons-chain%22

This was an issue with `FREETEXTTABLE` (loose match) versus `CONTAINSTABLE` (exact match). If we detect a quoted phrase in the search, we now switch to `CONTAINSTABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for addressing ths Jeff!

Comment: Did this somehow break again? The search for phrases seems to be loose to me...

Answer (score 6):

This still seems broken. I just searched on SO for "get operation", and the first hit was [checking, operation successful after any LinqToSql operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113435/checking-operation-successful-after-any-linqtosql-operation). It does not contain the phrase.

The closest it comes to matching is in a comment:

> You would **get** an exception related to the update **operation** failure.

Comment: that is odd, and I can't repro that with other quoted phrases. I am guessing get is dropped as a noise word?

Comment: yep, searching for "operation" and "get operation" (with the quotes) produces identical results. The SQL Server full text engine doesn't like the word "get".

Comment: Someone please tell the SQL Server full text engine to talk to the TFS group about their error messages. :-)

Comment: The search "alternatives to make" (in quotes) also fails the same way: lots of posts containing "alternatives" but not "make", and then finally about 20 posts down there is one titled "Promising alternatives to make".

Comment: The search "choices are" also does not work.