# When will searching for exact phrase be fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, exact-phrase-search

It seems like nobody observes [Searching for exact phrase seems broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13536/searching-for-exact-phrase-seems-broken) anymore. That's why I'm trying to bring this problem to the attention again.

[+python +custom +import](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bpython%20%2bcustom%20%2bimport&submit=search) gives 999 results while [+python "custom import"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bpython%20%22custom%20import%22&submit=search) gives 5,000+ results...

**When will searching for exact phrase be fixed?**

Btw, shall I delete `status-completed` tag on the original question?

Comment: I dare you to attempt to delete that tag.

Comment: It sounds like it was fixed and then re-broke, so no; posting a new bug is right. And you can't delete moderator-only tags anyway

Comment: @PopularDemand: Is that even possible? I've been wandering for quite some time now, but I never dared to try it out...

Comment: @Dennis It was; they [fixed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/why-am-i-allowed-to-delete-moderator-only-tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** `+` is no longer needed here just enter your words and phrases to search:

For example: [python "custom import"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20%22custom%20import%22)

---

<s>Like every other term you want to be a "*must* be present", use `+` on the phrase as well:</s>

```
+python +"custom import"
```

[You'll only get 8 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bpython%20%2b%22custom%20import%22&submit=search), note though [your top results are still the same](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bpython%20%22custom%20import%22&submit=search), since we prioritize results that match *all* terms over those that match *some* terms.

Comment: It would seem that the quotes only work for exact-phrase searches when accompanied by `+`, i.e. instead of surrounding phrases with `" "` you do so with `+" "`.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - what makes you think that?